# Cross subdomain PHPSESSID on localhost

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, wildcard-subdomain

I am on Windows 7 using WAMP, and I am trying to share the `PHPSESSID` across subdomains.

In my code I set: `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.web.local');`

When I go to `test.web.local` I get a different PHPSESSID than `web.local`

I want to be able to share the `PHPSESSID` in `$_COOKIE` accross the subdomains.

What am I doing wrong?

- Also running Wildcard based subdomains via Acrylic DNS Proxy custom hosts file.
- Another thing, if I `echo phpinfo()` on both domains, the `session.cookie_domain` directive has the same value on both.

Comment: .web.local are the subdomains of web.local (doesn't include web.local itself)

Comment: I tried setting it to `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.local');` but no avail, same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use `session_set_cookie_params` to share session across subdomain and you use need to use it on every pages (use it on main domain and subdomain). For example:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.web.local');    
session_start();
```

Noted that you need to use it before `session_start()`. For more information. Read the [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) documentation here.